# The scroll position (contentOffset) of a UITableView within a UISplitViewController changes when application enters the background

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am running XCode 7.3.1 and iOS 9.3. Using XCode's default Master-Detail application template (a `UISplitViewController` containing a master `UITableViewController` and a detail `UIViewController`), running on an iPad Air 2 simulator, the scroll position within the table changes when pressing the home button and then resuming the application: the table visibly scrolls up. It doesn't happen on an iPhone simulator.

A recording of this, from creation of the template XCode project to it running on the simulator can be seen [here](https://vid.me/uzLI).

What is causing this? Is there a way to prevent it?

To just see the table jump behaviour see the following gif:

[image: a screen recording]

Comment: Hey Andrew. I also created a new Master-Detail application, added 100 items, pressed home and opened the App again. Only the scrollbar flickers, but I cannot see the application changing the `contentOffset`. Are you sure you didn't change anything else?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, I'm pretty sure, but I will recreate the whole thing again just in case. The glitch does seem to be a bit intermittent. Can you force quit and try again, having scrolled down a little in the table and selected an item?

Comment: I will try again, but I tried it with different scroll positions and different selected/unselected cells.

Comment: Hi Alex, I recreated the template master-detail application  again, and still see the table jumping. The amount it jumps by is erratic. I have recorded the whole thing (creating the project, running it, experiencing the glitch), which I will attach to the question once I manage to upload the file. Thanks

Comment: Oh good, I'll take a look

Comment: Hi @Alex, I've just finished uploading that [video](https://vid.me/uzLI). If you can see anything I'm doing wrong, do let me know! PS I Reset Contents and Settings on the iPad simulator just prior to recording.

Comment: Wow, now it happens for me too... I noticed by setting an observer on the `tableView`s `contentOffset` that the frame is adjusted while going to background. Maybe it's a bug in the `_updateMasterViewControllerFrame` implementation of `UISplitViewController`, that is called when the system wants the application to take a Snapshot from the screen. Can you fix this by saving the contentOffset in `applicationWillEnterBackground` and resetting it when the application becomes active again?

Comment: Glad it's reproducible! Thanks for the update. I will experiment with manually adjusting the contentOffset as the app enters the background as you suggest...